# Saved MATLAB figures open differently in different versions?

Tags: matlab

I have a bunch of saved figures that were generated using MATLAB2016b. They have legends, and some annotations; text boxes, arrows etc which were created using the interactive plot tools.

Now I can open these figures in MATLAB2016b and all is well, but if I try to open them in MATLAB2016a (different PC), the annotations have shifted relative to the data (data axis limits are unchanged), and the legend size is dramatically different. What I mean by that is that when I saved the figure, the legend may have a position vector such as:

0.7675    0.1995    0.1200    0.1521

But if I open the figure in 2016a the legend takes up the whole screen. If i query the legend position;

> f = gcf;
>   f.Children

ans =

2x1 graphics array:

Legend    (Before Growth, After Growth, Cubic Fit Before, Cubic Fit After)

Axes      (Axis title)

> f.Children(1).Position

ans =

-0.0250   -0.0945    1.0500    1.1890

and to check:

> get(0, 'Units')

ans =

normalized

So this seems like very strange behaviour to me. I first suspected different units being used between the two versions, but they are both using normalized units. Seems weird that negative position values would be generated i.e outside the screen.

I have also checked the root settings for screen resolution (after setting the units to pixels with which I can compare my PC settings):

> set(0, 'Units', 'Pixels')
>
> get(0)

```
     CallbackObject: [0x0 GraphicsPlaceholder]
           Children: [4x1 Figure]
      CurrentFigure: [1x1 Figure]
 FixedWidthFontName: 'Courier New'
   HandleVisibility: 'on'
   MonitorPositions: [1 1 1600 900]
             Parent: [0x0 GraphicsPlaceholder]
    PointerLocation: [795 89]
        ScreenDepth: 32
ScreenPixelsPerInch: 96
         ScreenSize: [1 1 1600 900]
  ShowHiddenHandles: 'off'
                Tag: ''
               Type: 'root'
              Units: 'pixels'
           UserData: []
```

And 1600 x 900 is in agreement with the PC display settings.

So I am unsure of what else to try. I am wondering if anyone knows if this sort of thing is related to some setting, or if there is an inherently different method of handling these types of graphics objects between the two versions?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Just for clarification: You do both PC's have the same (1600 x 900) screen resolution?

Comment: @Leander Moesinger Both PC's do not have the same screen resolution. However, the machine that is giving me the trouble had previously had 2012b installed on it, and figures generated and saved on the other (2016b) machine would open perfectly fine in 2012b.